# Submit form once

Tags: javascript

Please help I use this script to perform automatic submit and reload but I want it to perform only once ? how can I make this only load once not every 3000(3sec)??

```
window.onload=function(){

var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

function submitform(){

  document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}

function autoRefresh(){
    clearTimeout(auto);
    auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 3000);

    }

}


 </script>


   <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Schedule Management</h2><hr />
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btn-add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> &nbsp; Add Schedule</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btn-view"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> &nbsp; View Schedule</button>
    <hr />
    <?php

 (isset($_POST["months"])) ? $dropDownVal = $_POST["months"] : $dropDownVal= date("n");

    ?>
    <div class="content-loader">
           <form method="post" action="index.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" > 
    Select a month <select name="months"  id="months" onchange='if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }'>
    <option value="0" <?php if ($dropDownVal==0) echo 'selected'; ?>>--------------</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if ($dropDownVal==1) echo 'selected'; ?>>January</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($dropDownVal==2) echo 'selected'; ?>>February</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($dropDownVal==3) echo 'selected'; ?>>March</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if ($dropDownVal==4) echo 'selected'; ?>>April</option>
    <option value="5" <?php if ($dropDownVal==5) echo 'selected'; ?>>May</option>
    <option value="6" <?php if ($dropDownVal==6) echo 'selected'; ?>>June</option>
    <option value="7" <?php if ($dropDownVal==7) echo 'selected'; ?>>July</option>
    <option value="8" <?php if ($dropDownVal==8) echo 'selected'; ?>>August</option>
    <option value="9" <?php if ($dropDownVal==9) echo 'selected'; ?>>September</option>
    <option value="10"<?php if ($dropDownVal==10) echo 'selected'; ?>>October</option>
    <option value="11"<?php if ($dropDownVal==11) echo 'selected';?>>November</option>
    <option value="12"<?php if ($dropDownVal==12) echo 'selected';?>>December</option>
    </select>

    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
```

I'm new to web so please help thanks

Answer (score -1):

If the goal is simply to ensure `submitform` is only called once, you can do the following:

```
var submitted = false;
function submitform(){
  if (!submitted) {
      submitted = true;
      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: not working applied this when I navigate the page it still show a blank table

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand the intent here.